# How can I open pdf files from a web page via android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf

I recently build an android app using webview in Android Studio but it doesn't open/download the pdf files from the website. Is there a way to let users open pdf files from a web page without adding them to the app. I want to update the pdf files on the website without having to change the app.

This is my code now:

```
    package com.something.app;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("something");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: (To be clear: I made an app from a website using the webview function in Android Studio. On the webpage i'm linking to are pdf files. If o try to open them in the app it doesn't do anything. If i open the pdf files in the web browser it sends you to the pdf file url. Is there a way you can do that in the app.)

Comment: A webview cannot display a pdf document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to open the PDF in device in-built browser:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdf_url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Or instead in web view:

```
 Webview webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl(pdf_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using pdfviewer for that. It's much better than using webview.
The link to the github is this: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

This is more useful because it's easy to use.

All you need is this code:

build gradle (app):

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

main.java

```
pdfView = (PdfView) findViewById(R.id.pdfview);
Uri a = new Uri("*your URL*");
pdfView.fromUri(a).load();
```

Comment: Is there a way to open a pdf from a web page without adding it to the script, so when you add an new pdf to the website it will instantly work?

Comment: That would depend on the website. Isn't the website just 1 pdf? Then how would you add a new pdf to that?

Comment: No the website is just an url. There is a pdf embedded in the website but I can't open it in my app.

Comment: If you go into inspect tab, you can find the actual URL of the pdf. Please share the URL so i can try to help you

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZHs3yfk1       this is for example a file I want to acces in the html. I can't share the site because you'll need to login. My goal is to open/download the pdf instantly without having to add the url to the app script.